# es6 maps setting without invoking map.set()

Tags: ecmascript-6, maps, invoke

I would like this map functionality explained:

```
 let m = new Map().set('items', ["a", "b", "c"]);

 console.log(m.get('items')); // ["a", "b", "c"]

 let n = m.get('items');

 console.log(n); // ["a", "b", "c"]

 n.push("d");

 console.log(n); // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

 console.log(m.get('items')); // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

How did the value 'd' get added to Map m without invoking Map.set()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one array, it's not cloned when `m.get('items')` is run but rather a reference to the array is provided.

You can confirm this by doing something like this:

`n === m.get('items')  // returns true`

Contrarily, two arrays are not equal even if they contain nothing. For example:

`[] === []  // returns false`

Pretty cool, I wasn't aware of this behavior but it makes sense. Nice!

Comment: Thank you, that was my hunch; that its by reference, Caught while trying to compare changes from an array retrieved from a map, and later comparing it to the `original` (which I now understand to the only)  mapped version. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @EranSch Yes, in JS values of rerference type (e.q object or arrays) are considered equal only if they store reference to the same location in memory (so both point to the same instance). And `[] === []`  creates two separate array instances

Answer (score 1):

Because `n` variable stores reference to array that is stored in the `m` Map (not copy of it) - so `n` variable stores regular array which of course has `push` method and `m` Map stores refernce to the same array so it sees updated array. So both `n` variable and map `items` entry share refernce to the same array. Please note that is typical behaviour for all JS reference types. If `m` map stored value of primitive type (e.g string) you'd have to use `set` to update it in your map.

Comment: Agreed, not speaking of the push method,but the map.get() that comes afterward. How did the `d` value get included into the map key/value pair 'items' without explicitly saying m.set('items', ["a","b""c","d"])?

Comment: @mhakes Because an array is an object, and the thing that is stored in this map is a reference to this object. This isn't relevant to maps in particular but to how JS works in general.

Comment: @EranSch and @estus are both saying the same thing. You're correct it is basic JS behavior I was thinking too `class like` that a map behaved like a class and would not fire unless invoked. Invoked is not the correct term for a reference, it is innate.